# Bulk sms is changing my URL

Tags: sms, civisms

When I send out a bulk sms with an URL, the URL is changed before it is sent out.

Original message in template:

- Hi John! Check out this link: wikipedia.org/somethingfunny

Received message on phone:

- Hi John! Check out this link: https://mysite.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=43&qid=70242

How to make CiviCRM not change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could schedule a bulk sms mailing (not send immediately), and then go into the database and change two values.

In the table civicrm_mailing, set the value 0 (from 1) on the fields url_tracking and open_tracking

Then you could send (or wait until the scheduled time is met)

Comment: Ah that is a nice hack

Answer (score 2):

My preferred solution is to use this extension (which should be 4.4 compatible) rather than manually digging around the database. Hope that helps!

https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.nosmsurltracking

Comment: @Flying I wrote this extension!  If it does NOT work on 4.4, please open an issue with the error message on its Github page.

Comment: @JonG I have not seen this extension, sounds perfect. Have you tried to have it in core for newer versions? However, I do think it is a bit too much to install an extension just for this, as I am concerned for the overhead costs of having too many extensions running...

Comment: @JonG Sorry, had looked at the info.xml file and it said it was compatible with 4.4

Comment: @Flying Extensions add relatively little overhead.  However, if you'd like to submit this as a patch to core, please do so!

Answer (score 0):

Disable tracking!

Need to add another 13 chars to sub answer...

Comment: But you cannot disable tracking for bulk sms. At least not on 4.4